# What does .NET stand for? Is it an acronym?

Tags: .net, definition, acronym

I've seen [pronunciation guides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155747(office.10).aspx) and all sorts of definitions of .NET as a *framework*, but no definition or explanation of the actual *name* of the framework.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.net_framework) doesn't seem to know.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165408/what-programming-acronyms-do-you-frequently-use-without-knowing-the-meaning-of) didn't cover it.

Anybody know?  Is it pure marketing-generated nonsense, or does it mean something?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

About 10 years ago, I was part of the large team in Redmond working on the set of projects which became ".net".  This was during the time the decisions were being made about what to name this work.  I can tell you from first-hand experience that ".net" is not an acroynm.

Instead, the [James Kovacs blog post](http://www.jameskovacs.com/blog/CNETHistoryLesson.aspx) that [Jim W posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495287/what-does-net-stand-for-is-it-an-acronym/1495319#1495319) is accurate: there was a long list of names that the team cycled through and rejected before finally settling on ".net".  The final name was chosen because it:

- mirrored the domain suffix of (at the time) every ISP, so was intended to remind users that "web-enabling your software" was the core scenario being targetted by this work
- was more approachable to business types and CIOs than geekier names like "Universal Runtime" or "COM+ 2.0"
- had practical benefits like: being short, easy to spell, globalized well, could leverage already-owned domain names for every Microsoft product, etc.
- actually passed legal/trademark review (surprisingly difficult!)

So it was intended to mean something, but more so by connotation rather than directly abbreviating or describing something.  In other words, the name was only partly marketing nonsense! ;-)

**More trivia**

I don't remember the exact positioning (it's been 10 years!), but I believe that the name ".net" was supposed cover three basic things:

1. ".net Framework" - a new framework for writing web-enabled apps
2. ".net web services" - a way of accessing Microsoft (and others') software over the web programmatically using open standards and protocols (anyone remember "Hailstorm"?)
3. ".net enterprise servers" - a set of products which made bulding web-enabled applications easier.

In practice, only the first meaning stuck with users.  The others morphed into other names (e.g. "Windows Server System") or were genericized by the public (e.g. "web services", SOA, etc.).  Anyway, that's why you don't see Microsoft products named "<product name here>.NET Server" any more-- Microsoft wisely decided to limit the ".net" name to the things that developers actually thought of as ".net"!

BTW, in addition to being short and easy to spell and say, ".net" as a name also helped with the web services strategy which Microsoft was persuing at the time, which revolved around (and still does) offering software which was also available in the cloud.  The idea was that we'd have, for example, Office.com for a hosted UI version, and Office.net for the APIs.  The name also was convenient since Microsoft already owned the .net domain-name variants for every microsoft product.

There's a funny T-Shirt (I think Don Box had them made?) which lists all the considered names (e.g. URT, COM+, etc.) with thick red lines drawn through all the names except the last one (".net"). The list goes from the top of the shirt right down the back, like a long list of cancelled Mötley Crüe tour dates, but nerdier!

Comment: I remember a lot of this.  For a very brief period, everything was being tagged ".NET".  There were rumors of even a Office.NET, if I recall.

Comment: "in addition to being short and easy to spell" - yeah, and I remember how much fun it was to google for anything .NET-related back in the day when it wasn't being treated as a special keyword by the search engines (so they'd just interpret it as "net", which is about as useless as it can get).

Comment: The shirt picture is not visible anymore: 5 years later, it's only a broken link.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :). Really help full and understandable. :)

Comment: `".net" was one of many names that the teams cycled through (and thankfully rejected) before settling on ".net"` Uhh. What? :D

Comment: @RenéSackers - you're right that sentence is unclear. I clarified it.

Comment: @JustinGrant Haha, I think I understood it after looking at it for 10 minutes with a colleague, but this is much better :P

Answer (score 25):

It's not an acronym.

> In the beginning - around 1997 - there
>   was Project Lightning. It was also
>   known as Project 42 because DevDiv
>   (Microsoft's Developer Division) lived
>   (and still lives) in Building 42 on
>   the Redmond Campus. (I've always
>   thought that was an awesome building
>   number for DevDiv with the little hat
>   tip to Douglas Adams' Hitchhikers
>   Guide to the Galaxy. I've always
>   wondered if it was intentional.) Early
>   press announcements referred to it as
>   "Next Generation Windows Services".
>   Eventually Project Lightning was
>   dubbed Microsoft .NET, though some
>   code names have been forever baked
>   into the system.
>
> Marketing was thinking of calling it
>   COM+ 2.0 or the Universal Runtime
>   (URT). Another idea was the COM Object
>   Runtime (COR). Hence mscorlib.dll,
>   which is still the assembly that holds
>   the CLR's main types and is the one
>   assembly that must be loaded in every
>   .NET app domain. (System.dll is often
>   loaded, but need not be. Mscorlib.dll
>   contains the code for System.String,
>   System.Int32, etc. You honestly can't
>   do anything without mscorlib.dll
>   loaded.)
>
> http://www.jameskovacs.com/blog/CNETHistoryLesson.aspx

Comment: I had always assumed mscorlib stood for Microsoft Core Library, since it's the core library of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Building 42 was a coincidence. And I believe DevDiv is much more spread-out these days.

Comment: Most of DevDiv is still in building 42. Most people from it that you see blogging on MSDN are there, as well.

Comment: I thought that "mscorlib" was for "MS Core Library".

Comment: I heard, at the time, that .Net was being marketed as COM+ way ahead of when the dev team could deliver it, and at some point, when they realized there was no way they were going to deliver on the schedule that the marketing team had been promising, they decided to add some features to MTS and deliver that as COM+ instead...

Comment: You haven't answered the real question.  We know .NET is not an acronym. So is it "pure marketing nonsense" or is there some other meaning?

Comment: And Don Box once joked that `mscoree.dll` would be the last COM DLL ever written.

Answer (score 3):

Someone told me.NET refers to the following:

(.)  -> Object Oriented
(NET)-> Network Enabled Technology

Answer (score 2):

from http://looselycoupled.com/glossary/.NET:

*"Microsoft's web services architecture, pronounced dot-net. Despite the capital letters, it's not an acronym. .NET is the brand name for a set of proprietary Microsoft frameworks and technologies founded on XML web services standards. Standards compliance means that applications written using .NET should interoperate with those written in rival architectures, such as J2EE, the distributed application infrastructure based on Sun's Java language. However, interoperability is not portability; .NET applications will only run on Microsoft platforms, such as Windows Server or Windows XP."*

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* it is called .NET. It just says what is means.

Comment: In spanish: "punto net" :D :D

Comment: That definition is not even accurate.  It looks like it was written 10 years ago when everyone thought .NET = web services and XML.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really stand for anything, but it is part of the naming scheme used by Microsoft in early 2000s, out of which (as far as I know), only the .NET Framework, and Visual Studio .NET, survived. It was supposed to be much more expansive - for example, Windows Server 2003 was supposed to be "Windows Server .NET".

There are no clear explanations, but it seems to be related to the marketing campaign which described the new wave of Microsoft tech as "Internet centric". If you saw the early PR materials for .NET Framework, they heavily emphasized Web Services, for example (it was all the craze back in the day, and MS played a large part in defining the WS-* stack). Then also it was said that Microsoft Passport would rule the world as a single-point authentication system.

These days, I guess it's just a brand.

Comment: I have a promotional Leatherman multitool that says "Windows .NET Server 2003" on it :)

Comment: I like the .NET framework but for the record I hate the name.  The versioning is confusing also.  There is the .NET runtime (or CLR) which is currently up to version 2.0 then there is the .NET framework which is currently up to version 3.5.

Comment: .NET 4 will reset versioning for all involved products to 4.0 (which means there won't be CLR 3.x).

Comment: Thank you Seth, I found this post searching for info on that Leatherman, as I too have have that "Pulse" model with Windows .NET Server 2003 and logo. (I don't know where I picked it up...)

Answer (score 2):

All I can remember from when the framework was first in beta is a ridiculous amount of press regarding the use of web services, and how the new framework by Microsoft was going to make all of that SOAP/web service stuff easier and better.  It's a stretch, but maybe that's why.  Not the greatest name, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I think it's supposed to sound like the end of a URL for a website (which is apparently known as a [top-level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain)). So .NET is kind of like .com, .biz, or .org. Microsoft wanted to make it sound like it's new programming environments were going to be very internet savvy.

Answer (score 0):

Many people think that ".NET" is for "Network Services", and they also think that .Net apps will have networking functionality. This is not totally true because .Net is a framework that does a lot more than just networking stuff.

This is a proof of how confusing the name ".Net" can be.

Answer (score -6):

.NET stands for Domain NETwork
 Domain for (.) Network for NET

Comment: If you're answering this for something like "www.example.net", you should really re-read the question.